# How to pause the FadeTo() method in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The functionality works like this: a single image pops up on the screen, after 5000ms another image overrides the previously shown image and during this process, it fades out. At a time maximum of five images are shown on the screen which eventually gets fade out as time passes.

There is a pause function that stops the sequence of images. The problem is as soon as a click happens, the latest cloned image stays as it is while all the remaining images in the background fade out.

How to freeze all the images when a mouse-click is triggered?

The delay() method won't be suitable for this scenario as a user might pause for an unknown duration of time.

Guidance/help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question lacks any attempt at solving this problem on your own. The idea is for you to try to get something to work and then come here with specific problems you are unable to resolve. Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: @RandyCasburn Hi Randy, thanks for the suggestion. I'm successfully able to pause/stop the recent cloned image, however, all the remaining images in the background are supposed to be paused as well, but they just fade out. I'm struggling to find the way ahead. How to freeze the screen (that is all images, not just the latest cloned image) is something I'm trying to figure out?

Comment: @RandyCasburn Can you give me some pointers to proceed with this problem? I can work on it and come back here to ask about a specific problem being encountered as suggested? Thanks